# Отсутствует перевод блока приветствия

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, мета

При открытии [Мета сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) не будучи авторизованным (можно открыть ссылку в приватном режиме), справа отображается блок приветствия, нуждающийся в переводе:

> [image: Welcome]

В transifex соответствующий текст не обнаружен.

> Welcome!
>   This site is for discussion about Stack Overflow на русском. You must have an account there to participate.

Запулил репорт на MSE: [Welcome message for per site metas is not able to localize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300032/339911)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как выяснилось на MSE, данный текст задается в настройках сайта, а не в Transifex. Предлагаю следующий перевод:

> Добро пожаловать!
>
> Этот сайт предназначен для **обсуждений** [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). У вас должна быть учётная запись на [основном сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) для участия на Мете.