# Перевод приветственного сообщения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Несколько мгновений после того, как участник задал свой первый вопрос, в правой части экрана показывается приветственное сообщение:

> [image: скриншот приветственного сообщения]

> Welcome!
>
> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for программистов. It's 100% free, no registration required.
>
> Got a question about the site itself? meta is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

Переведите его, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: Вероятно, текст задается где-то рядом с текстом из другого [баг-репорта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4079/176217).

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю следующий перевод:

> Добро пожаловать!
>
> Это сайт совместно редактируемых вопросов и ответов для {целевая аудитория}. Он на 100% бесплатен и не требует регистрации.
>
> Есть вопрос о самом сайте? Мета - это место для обсуждений того, какие вопросы подходят для сайта, какие метки стоит использовать и т.п.

Про отсутствие необходимости регистрации, конечно, стоит дополнительно уточнить, что здесь имеется в виду [именно просмотр сообщений, а не написание новых](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120712/339911).
Судя по [ответу Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260309/339911) часть про требование регистрации вообще должна быть выпилена.

Насчёт подходящей формулировки для "целевой аудитории" есть соответствующий вопрос: [Целевая аудитория сайтов Stack Exchange](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3680/176217)

Comment: Спасибо, из незначительных замечаний — можно, пожалуйста, тире заменить на длинное и в `и т.п.` добавить пробел (`и т. п.`)